# How do you call a linear programming problem when the solution should be "constrained" to a norm?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, global-optimization

(apologies for the n00b question)

Let's say we have a vector of length $n$, with to-be-determined values: $a_1, a_2, ...,a_n$.

And we have information that partial sums of these elements are equal to something, say:
$$
a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{k_1} = A_{1} \\
a_{k_1+1} + a_{k_1+2} + ... + a_n = B_1 \\
a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{k_2} = A_2 \\
a_{k_2+1} + a_{k_2+2} + ... + a_n = B_2 \\
...\\
a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{k_m} = A_m \\
a_{k_m+1} + a_{k_m+2} + ... + a_n = B_m \\
$$

Where $m<<n$: so we have much fewer such $m$ equations/constraints than the $n$ unknown values $a_i$.

If we want to know which combination of $a_i$ values can solve these equations, there are probably infinite many such combinations (or 0). So I'd like to add two constraints to this:

1. $a_i>0$ for any i.
2. I want the solution with $a_i$ values that are as "similar" to each other as possible. For example, keeping $\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i - \bar a)^2$ as small as possible (L2 norm). Where $\bar a = \sum \frac{a_i}{n}$.

How is such optimization problem called? (would also love to know how to solve it, but I assume that once I have the name, I can find solvers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are willing to replace $a_i > 0$ by $a_i \ge 0$,
then this becomes a **quadratic program**. Indeed,
it can be formulated as
\begin{align*}
\text{Minimize}\quad & \frac12 a^\top Q a +  q^\top a, \\
\text{such that} \quad & C a = d, \\
& a \ge 0.
\end{align*}
Here, $Q$ and $C$ are matrices of appropriate size and $q$ and $d$ are vectors (these objects come from your data). Moreover, the matrix $Q$ is positive semidefinite.

[If you insist on keeping $a_i > 0$, the corresponding problem might fail to have solutions.]

Comment: I'm fine that a could be 0. Thanks for the response. So Ca=d is the equations I wrote above?

Comment: Yes, you encode these conditions via a linear system of equations.

Comment: Thanks. Any pointers for how to do this? When I look at wikipedia and software implementations they seem to require " A^T b >= b0". How then do I create a constraint that does  "Ca = d"?

Comment: $Ca = d$ is equivalent to "$C a \le d$ and $Ca \ge d$".

Comment: I just don't see how the software allows for larger-equal sign. Oh well, I'll see what I can do...

Comment: @Tal Galili $Ca \ge d$ can be rewritten as $-Ca \le -d$

Comment: @MarkL.Stone - I think I'll go hide under my blanket now. How embarrassing :D  (Thanks <3 )